# You tube videos are not Playing in iOS6

Tags: youtube, ios6

I am using iOS6 beta youtube videos which are not playing in my app in this version.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: and the question is... ?

Comment: I had the same problem. Anyone have informations ?

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but if you can still reproduce it, could you add an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) ?

Answer (score 1):

Please write the way you add youtube video.
Because the only thing a had read is that the Youtube app is no longer in iOS6, but it must keep working. Anyway try with

```
NSString* embeddedCode = @"embed code of the youtube video"
UIWebView* videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]; 
[videoView loadHTMLString:embeddedCode baseURL:nil];
[self.window addSubview:videoView];
```

Hope it works, but in case it doesn't just comment and I can try another thing.

Comment: Not true. First, you are missing a lot of needed code. Second, this will not work on a device running iOS6.